# how to use facebook login properly across website .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a master page of my web app using asp.net.
And there are for eg three other pages in which i am performing some facebook activites like upload image from facebook album ,autocomplete facebook friends and login also

On My **Master** Page i have written this code for facebook login

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '1499702230242110', // App ID
                status: false, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true, // parse XFBML

            }); 
};
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {



if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // performing insert query after login and reloading the page
    //insert query and on sucess reload function
    document.location.href = loc;
}

});
function Login() {
            flag_set_def = 0;
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // getUserInfo();
                    //update_insert_details();
                    flag_set_def = 0;
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, { scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos' });


        }

<a class="my_icon" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="Login()"  />
```

On Master page sign in works smoothly and also query is fired 
Note the anchor tag(sign in button ) is on the master page (i.e header of the app)

But my problem is other pages 
for eg Page A 
now here if i click the sign-in button theres error
Code on this page

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '1499702230242110', // App ID
                    status: false, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true, // parse XFBML

                }); 
    };
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {

    // performing insert query after login and reloading the page

    });
```

I have tried `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {` instead of      `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {`

but its gets reloaded so i am confused what shud i use exactly to run the login system smoothly allthrough the pages